# Offscreen convertToBlob very slow

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I've been experimenting with the HTML canvas for a while, and this code below takes 1 second to finish, that is very slow:

```
    const offscreen = new OffscreenCanvas(640, 360); 
    const ctx = offscreen.getContext('2d'); // Chrome only
    const bitmap = e.data.data;
    ctx.drawImage(bitmap, 0, 0);
    let start = performance.now();
    offscreen.convertToBlob({ type: 'image/jpeg', quality : 0.5}).then(function(blob) {
        let now = performance.now();
        console.log('Convert to blob took: ' + (now-start) + ' milliseconds'); // e.g log: 1085.1800000000512 milliseconds
    });
```

Code is running in a web worker.

What is the best way to improve speed in this context? Is my code wrong?

Comment: Yes that is very slow, 640-360 to jpeg is so trivial!!. There is nothing wrong with the code Note promise will not resolve until current execution context is idle, so time is of all code below the convert.  Workers only if free threads and RAM. On Chrome get core count (+virtual cores "hyper threads") with `clientInformation.hardwareConcurrency` More workers than that can result in slower overall performance. Chrome open task manager to make sure you have free processing time. Open task manager on device OS to make sure you have the resources.

Answer (score 1):

That was a bug in Chromium, which got fixed by [this commit](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/09514b7fbd4fb14ce12a43bc7f4807179612fa94) (available in Chrome v83).

The message from this commit:

> Don't schedule idle tasks for workers
>
> Idle tasks take much longer on worker threads because
> requestAnimationFrame isn't there. For this test:
> https://chromium-review.googlesource.com/c/chromium/src/+/2124971
>
> Without this change worker convertToBlob takes ~400ms
> With this change worker convertToBlob takes ~10ms

And if interested, the code I used to find the correct bisect range:

```js
if( !window.OffscreenCanvasRenderingContext2D ) {
  throw new Error( "Your browser doesn't support the 2D context of the Offscreen canvas" );
}
// This code demonstrate how calling 100 times convertToBlob
// doesn't end up in 100 x single-time execution
// i.e the actual processing time is much less than the time we have to wait...
const script = `
onmessage= async (e) => {
  const offscreen = new OffscreenCanvas( 800, 600 ); 
  const ctx = offscreen.getContext( '2d' );
  const bitmap = await fetch( 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/47/PNG_transparency_demonstration_1.png' )
    .then( (resp) => resp.blob() )
    .then( createImageBitmap );

{
  const beginning = performance.now();
  const proms = [];
  
  for( let i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) {
    ctx.drawImage( bitmap, i, i );
    ctx.clearRect( 0, 0, 100, 100 );
    ctx.fillText( i , 50, 50 );
    const start = performance.now();
    proms.push( offscreen.convertToBlob()
      .then( blob => {
        const now = performance.now();
        postMessage( '('+ i + ') in sync loop' + ' - took:' + (now - start)
        );
      } )
     );
  }
  const blobs = await Promise.all( proms );
  const duration = performance.now() - beginning;
  postMessage( 'all done in ' + duration + ' -> ' + Math.round( duration / 10 ) + 'ms in average' );
}
{
  const beginning = performance.now();
  const proms = [];
  
  for( let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    ctx.drawImage( bitmap, i, i );
    ctx.clearRect( 0, 0, 100, 100 );
    ctx.fillText( i , 50, 50 );
    const start = performance.now();
    proms.push( offscreen.convertToBlob()
      .then( blob => {
        const now = performance.now();
        postMessage( '('+ i + ') in rAF loop took - ' + (now - start) );
      } )
    );
    await new Promise(res => requestAnimationFrame(res));
  }
  
  const blobs = await Promise.all( proms );
  const duration = performance.now() - beginning;
  postMessage( 'all done in ' + duration + ' -> ' + Math.round( duration / 10 ) + 'ms in average' );

}
{
  let duration = 0;
  const proms = [];

  for( let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    const beginning = performance.now();
    ctx.drawImage( bitmap, i, i );
    ctx.clearRect( 0, 0, 100, 100 );
    ctx.fillText( i , 50, 50 );
    const start = performance.now();
    proms.push( offscreen.convertToBlob()
      .then( blob => {
        const now = performance.now();
        duration += now - start;
        postMessage( '('+ i + ') in timeout loop took - ' + (now - start) );
      } )
    );
    await wait( 500 );
  }
  const blobs = await Promise.all( proms );
  postMessage( 'all done in ' + duration + ' -> ' + Math.round( duration / 10 ) + 'ms in average' );

}

};
function wait(ms) { return new Promise( (res) => setTimeout( res, ms ) ); }
`;
const blob = new Blob( [ script ] );
const worker = new Worker( URL.createObjectURL( blob ) );
worker.onmessage = (e) => console.log( e.data );
worker.postMessage("");
```

From this test, in Chrome < 83 I get approximately 200ms on average for the two first tests (sync and requestAnimationFrame), and 900ms (oO) with the setTimeout test.
These tests allowed me to understand that it's actually not only "slow", but that there is a huge delay added before every step, where nothing happens.

With the latest Canary version, all these tests return 30ms on average.

#### So there is unfortunately not much you can do,

apart from working from Canary and wait until Chrome releases the v83 on branch before you release your code publicly... But still note that batching several calls will only have some delay, it won't take incremental time to process.

---

Now, since OP wants to convert an ImageBitmap to a Blob in a Worker, this won't help, but **an ugly** workaround for other readers is to make that conversion in the main thread, either by first converting the canvas to an ImageBitmap (`convertToImageBitmap()` is fast enough) and then sending back this ImageBitmap to the main thread, either by using a detached HTMLCanvasElement and calling its `toBlob` method.

```js
if( !window.OffscreenCanvasRenderingContext2D ) {
  throw new Error( "Your browser doesn't support the 2D context of the Offscreen canvas" );
}

const script = `
onmessage= async (e) => {
  const offscreen = e.data; 
  const ctx = offscreen.getContext( '2d' );
  const bitmap = await fetch( 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/47/PNG_transparency_demonstration_1.png' )
    .then( (resp) => resp.blob() )
    .then( createImageBitmap );

  // probably do something else here...
  ctx.drawImage( bitmap, 0, 0 );
  
  const start = Date.now(); // start measuring from now
  postMessage( start );

};
`;
const blob = new Blob( [ script ] );
const worker = new Worker( URL.createObjectURL( blob ) );
const canvas = document.getElementById( 'canvas' );
const offscreen = canvas.transferControlToOffscreen();
worker.postMessage( offscreen, [ offscreen ] );

worker.onmessage = (e) => {
  const start = e.data;
  canvas.toBlob( (blob) => {
    console.log( 'Transfer to Blob took', Date.now() - start + 'ms' );
  } );
};
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="800" height="600"></canvas>
```

Comment: Strange quote. `requestAnimationFrame` is in workers.

Comment: @gman [here is a discussion about it.](https://chromium-review.googlesource.com/c/chromium/src/+/2124703). Sounds like committer probably got confused, and thought [internal]requestIdleCallback was linked to requestAnimationFrame, but apparently, it's just that [internal]rIC that has a huge delay in Workers.